# Continously Update Preview alert on SDL Tridion UI 2013

Tags: 2013, siteedit

I found error in `cd_preview` log file of staging website which is

ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction
2013-12-12 16:05:03,727 TRACE SessionsCleanerMonitor - Could not perform sessions clean-up. Will retry in 60000 milliseconds.
com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionHandlingException: Could not clean session storage after session expired: Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction
at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.expireSession(SessionManagerImpl.java:443) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:230) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:52) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]

**UPDATE : Getting different error now after updating to 2013 sp1**

```
ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Rollback took place, didn't remove
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.remove(JPABaseDAO.java:155) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAItemDAO.remove(JPAItemDAO.java:246) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionWrapperFactory.deleteItemMeta(SessionWrapperFactory.java:184) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionWrapperFactory.cleanupSessionData(SessionWrapperFactory.java:161) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.expireSession(SessionManagerImpl.java:414) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:230) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:52) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.DeleteEvent.<init>(DeleteEvent.java:45) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:801) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:883) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365) ~[spring-orm.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.remove(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.remove(JPABaseDAO.java:145) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are 2 different issues.

The reason why Update Preview button is always flashing is likely linked to the fact that something is missing when updating. Do you actually see updates after clicking on the button?

You may also verify the steps Tridion takes when you click on that button. I outlined the actions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802033/866454) on Stack Overflow. I don't think the issue is the same you're seeing, but following the trail of what Tridion is doing will help you narrow down what could be the root cause.

Comment: Both web.configs (web service and staging site contains reference to [Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule] inside [System.webserver\modules]. Session preview web service contains [Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll] inside bin folder and [cd_preview_ambient.jar] and [cd_preview_webservice.jar] inside lib folders.Cd_ambient_conf.xml contains only [<Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>] inside [Cartridges] node.i can see data in session prieview database and Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.dll also placed on staging site only.

Answer (score 1):

Module `<add name="PreviewContentModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" />` was missing in webconfig file of staging website